# Looking for an efficient implementation of pytorch matrix multiplcation to prevent large memory usage

Tags: matrix, pytorch, broadcasting

`torch.matmul` in pytorch has functions of broadcasting, which may consume too much memory.I am looking for efficient implementations to prevent excessive memory usage.

**For example**,the input tensor has size as
`adj.size()==[1,3000,3000]`
`s.size()==torch.Size([235, 3000, 10])`
`s.transpose(1, 2).size()==torch.Size([235, 10, 3000])`
The task is to calculate

```
link_loss = adj - torch.matmul(s, s.transpose(1, 2)) #
link_loss = torch.norm(link_loss, p=2)
```

The original code lies in the torch extension package `torch_geometric`.It is in the definition of the  function [dense_diff_pool](https://rusty1s.github.io/pytorch_geometric/build/html/_modules/torch_geometric/nn/dense/diff_pool.html#dense_diff_pool).
`torch.matmul(s, s.transpose(1,2))` will consume excessive memory(my computer has only memory space around 2GB) ,raising the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       torch.matmul(s, s.transpose(1, 2))
>
> RuntimeError: $ Torch: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 7GB.
>   Buy new RAM! at ..\aten\src\TH\THGeneral.cpp:201

The original code by the author of the package contains `torch.matmul(s, s.transpose(1, 2)).size()==[235,3000,3000]` which is larger than 7GB.

My attemptation is that I tried to use a `for` iteration

```
batch_size=235
link_loss=torch.sqrt(torch.stack([torch.norm(adj - torch.matmul(s[i], s[i].transpose(0, 1)), p=2)**2 for i in range(batch_size)]).sum(dim=0))
```

This `for` loop is known to be slower than using broadcasting or other pytorch built-in functions. 
*Question*:
Is there any faster implementation, better than using [ ... for ...].
I am a newbie on learning pytorch. Thanks.